# phonegap build not going further

Tags: cordova, gradle, phonegap, java-6

it is my first time with phonegap and native app development
iam trying to build with command`cordova run android`
it download some gradle files and unzip them and many other file and now it not going further after 2 hour[image]

```
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/nekohtml/nekohtml/1.9.6.2/nekohtml-1.9.6.2.jar
```

what to do now should i stop npm or what..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Stop the npm
2. Close any editor if open
3. Run CMD as administrator
   And try these
4. *npm cache clean*
5. *Cordova clean*
6. *Cordova prepare*
7. *Cordova build*